# How can I solve the pytorch mismatch error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I've got pytorch mismatch error in following code:

```
# Visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

digit_size = 28
z_sample = np.random.rand(1, latent_dim) # random
z_sample.dtype = 'float32'
z_sample = torch.tensor(z_sample) 
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 1))

for i in range(10):
    c = np.zeros((1, cond_dim), dtype='float32')
    c[i] = 1
    c = torch.tensor(c)
    cvae.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        img = cvae.decoder(z_sample, c)
        # reshape (if needed)

    plt.subplot(1, i+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(img, cmap='Greys_r',)
plt.show()
##### test #####
print(np.size(z_sample))
print(latent_dim)
```

I defined `latent_dim` equals to 2.
I know where the error is coming from.
it's come from these lines:

```
z_sample = np.random.rand(1, latent_dim) # random
z_sample.dtype = 'float32'
z_sample = torch.tensor(z_sample)
```

in first line, I defined a 1*2 random vector
but after I changed it from 'array' to 'tensor' it gives me 1*4 vector so I got this mismatch error.

anyone know how can I fix it?
it also still should be 'float32'.

***EDIT:***
the CVAE is:

```
class CVAE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, x_dim, h_dim1, h_dim2, z_dim, c_dim):
        super(CVAE, self).__init__()

        # encoder part
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(x_dim + c_dim, h_dim1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(h_dim1, h_dim2)
        self.fc31 = nn.Linear(h_dim2, z_dim)
        self.fc32 = nn.Linear(h_dim2, z_dim)
        # decoder part
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(z_dim + c_dim, h_dim2)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(h_dim2, h_dim1)
        self.fc6 = nn.Linear(h_dim1, x_dim)

    def encoder(self, x, c):
        concat_input = torch.cat((x, c), 1)
        h = F.relu(self.fc1(concat_input))
        h = F.relu(self.fc2(h))
        return self.fc31(h), self.fc32(h)

    def sampling(self, mu, log_var):
        std = torch.exp(0.5*log_var)
        eps = torch.randn_like(std)
        return eps.mul(std).add(mu) # return z sample

    def decoder(self, z, c):
        concat_input = torch.cat((z, c), 1)
        h = F.relu(self.fc4(concat_input))
        h = F.relu(self.fc5(h))
        return F.sigmoid(self.fc6(h))

    def forward(self, x, c):
        mu, log_var = self.encoder(x.view(-1, 784), c)
        z = self.sampling(mu, log_var)
        return self.decoder(z, c), mu, log_var
```

the model is:

```
# Create Model (change None)
cond_dim = train_loader.dataset.train_labels.unique().size(0)
latent_dim = 2
cvae = CVAE(x_dim=28*28, h_dim1=512, h_dim2=256, z_dim=latent_dim, c_dim=cond_dim)

# Device setting
cvae = cvae.to(device)
```

and the error is:

RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [1 x 14], m2: [12 x 256] at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:197

Comment: Can you paste the complete error? And, what are `cond_dim` and `cvae`?

Comment: @kHarshit I added them to my post.